# Jruby: Requiring jars with classpath in manifest

Tags: java, jar, jruby

I'm trying to require a jar with jruby 1.7.4 and get different results for Windows and Linux.
My folder layout is as follows:

```
/current_folder
|--/lib
   |--lib.jar
   |--dep.jar
```

The lib.jar uses some classes from dep.jar and has a manifest like the following one:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: lib.Main
Class-Path: dep.jar
```

Everything works OK for both Windows and Linux when I run the program contained in lib.jar with `java -jar absolute/path/to/lib.jar`.

But when I try the following, it works only for Linux.

1. `cd` to `current_folder`.
2. Run `jirb`.
3. Execute `require 'java'` and `require 'absolute/path/to/lib.jar'`.
4. Use classes from lib.jar.

For Windows it cannot load classes from dep.jar and fails.

**But** if for Windows I `cd` to `lib` folder, everything starts working again.

So, what am I doing wrong? I'd like everything to work for Windows in the same way as it does for Linux. I.e., I'd prefer to have the classpath for lib.jar stay in its manifest; I don't want to specify all its dependencies explicitly when using it from `jirb`.